# Does TinyMCE allows immutable entities (the counterpart of CKEditor's "widget" feature)?

Tags: wordpress, ckeditor, tinymce, wysiwyg, tinymce-4

Is it possible to insert immutable entities in TinyMCE?

Here's what I mean: [CKEditor Widgets](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_widgets.html)

Examples:
[Latex - MathJax](https://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/mathjax.html), [Placeholder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/placeholder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a noneditable plugin you can use to effectively treat any amount of arbitrary HTML as one “character” in the editor. You can copy, paste, etc. the entire non editable region just as you can a single character. See the documentation page for the plugin for more details.

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/noneditable/

Comment: I have the following usecase - I have written a custom plugin that adds a mceNonEditable div to the editor which also has an mceEditable div within itself so that text can be added. Now I want to be able to copy the entire nonEditable section (along with its editable part) and paste it "within" the editable part. i.e, I want to create Nested nonEditable (aka, Widgets) sections. My problem is, I am unable to acheive Nesting i.e, the editor creates another copy “outside” of the nonEditable div, whereas I want it to create it within itself. How can I do this ? I am using TinyMCE 6.3.x